# How can I change the size of each image?

Tags: html, css

So I have a range of images and I want to make each one a different size, they are sitting within a container that makes them resize with browser

```
.contentwrapper {
display: block;
position: relative;
margin:0 auto;
width:90vw;
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
margin-top: 150px;
}

img {
max-width: 75%;
max-height: 75%;
height: auto;
position: relative;
}
```

How can I make each image a different size without effecting the size of the others? for example the first image max-width: 75%;
max-height: 75%; and the second max-width: 55%;
max-height: 55%; etc

```
    <div class="contentwrapper">
    <img 
    src="img/1.%20Generation%20anxiety%20front%20+%20back%20copy2.png">

    <img style="float: right" 
    src="img/2.%20GenerationAnxiety%20page%202,2.png">
    </div>
```

Comment: since its a lot of images, would some images have the same width and height? or would they all have random values?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you can’t just give each image it’s own class name and define their height and width individually?

Answer (score 0):

CSS Flexbox does the trick. Please take a look at this [Gallary Grid](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_grid_responsive.asp) link. I hope you r looking for same.

Answer (score 0):

CSS allows you to assign styles to:

- tags
- tag chain
- a collection of tags
- by tag attribute
- by number of the tag
- by tag class
- by tag id
- inline
- all the above with "!important"

If for one item is assigned same property more than once, its take one that has the highest priority and the last in css list. In this case, the properties with the ending "!important" have the highest priority.
Inline css rule has the first priority, then by id, then by class and so on...

If you want to use a formula, you should think about using a css rules with the js function.

I tried to reflect the logic on a simple example here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PaWNpj

Second example here:

```
jQuery("img").each(function(i) {
  var size = 75 - 20 * i;
  if (size < 10) {
    size = 10;
  }
  size = size + "%";
  $(this)
    .css("max-width", size)
    .css("max-height", size);
});
```

but you can just use css rules:

```
img:nth-child(1) {
    max-width: 75%;
    max-height: 75%;
}

img:nth-child(2) {
    max-width: 55%;
    max-height: 55%;
}

img:nth-child(3) {
    max-width: 35%;
    max-height: 35%;
}

img:nth-child(4) {
    max-width: 15%;
    max-height: 15%;
}
```